# XOR operand type mismatch

Tags: assembly, x86-64, shellcode, immediate-operand

I'm trying to get around some input character restrictions by encrypting some data. However, when i try and XOR rbx back to my desired value I get an error stating operand mismatch. Am i missing something here?

```
xor esi, esi
movabs rbx, 0x4a510d0d4c4b400d
xor rbx, 0x2222222222222222
```

Comment: Use `movl` to move a 32-bit immediate to a 64-bit register, use `movq` instead to sign-extend and `movabsq` for full 64-bit immediates.

Comment: @Sebastian: Or XOR with something that can fit in a sign-extended 32-bit immediate, like `0xffffffffa2222222`.  The choice appears arbitrary here, since this is just obscuring constants and avoiding `00` bytes in shellcode.  In this case it's the constant is `0x68732f2f6e69622f` which looks like an ASCII string.  So in NASM you could write ```mov rbx, `hello w\n` ^ 0xffffffffa2222222``` / `xor rbx, 0xffffffffa2222222`.  It's annoying when people obscure their ASCII in shellcode source by manually encoding it in hex.  Just use an assembler that doesn't suck to make your machine code.